# Payment not completing

Tags: php, opencart

When completing a payment the user gets redirected to our payment gateway and the transaction seems to complete, redirecting the user back to our store.

Payments are processed but the OpenCart store doesn't display, just gets a white screen. When logging into the OpenCart admin area, the order is not displayed.

However, the database does receive the information when we look at it in phpMyAdmin.

Could this be a memory issue? Any other hints / clues / ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: What payment gateway? Code from callback method? Error logs? Or shall we divine?

Comment: Sorry Shadyyxx - had to pay a contractor to do this, forgot to check back here.